# How to delete files on a read-only filesystem not found in the output of `mount`?

Tags: kubernetes, debian, mount

I want to `rm -rf /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/` to delete the `default` Kubernetes service account for testing anonymous API access.

However, running the above command shows that many of the files are on a read-only filesystem, so I want to temporarily remount the filesystem (`mount -o remount`) to delete the files.

Now, how can I see which filesystem in the output of `mount` to remount? None of the filesystems below are mounted on a `/var/run/` path. The closest match is `/var/lib/` in the options for the overlay filesystem mounted on `/`.

How can I safely delete the files under `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`?

```
root@ctf1-deploy1-6fd44cbcd6-vrckg:~# rm -rf /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..data': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_03_25_08_59_25.631059710/namespace': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_03_25_08_59_25.631059710/ca.crt': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/..2020_03_25_08_59_25.631059710/token': Read-only file system
root@ctf1-deploy1-6fd44cbcd6-vrckg:~# mount
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/ZLOIVO6AXDQFZ3NU3O4VYG5QJC:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/MZY5Y3MJC6IVDUFSNOQEU55JZJ:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/E5HAR5VEWTG6MCFYN22KDJNMK3:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/5Z2WGKVJRNGPXV5QIFR5CWHJSE:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/U5HNVHXGGWRIGBX3XJV5CW5VIZ:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/TI5WPYBQSWQJXBMOY7DT5DN26Z:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/XOZNIEPFIZTLP2HEHFKL66H4EO,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ea51426b9eb47af0faf53e60a25b6cffae64c3338130663efd1068c7d2ffb20/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ea51426b9eb47af0faf53e60a25b6cffae64c3338130663efd1068c7d2ffb20/work)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /dev/termination-log type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /etc/resolv.conf type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /etc/hostname type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /etc/hosts type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k)
tmpfs on /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/bus type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/fs type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/irq type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/sys type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/sysrq-trigger type proc (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/acpi type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/kcore type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/keys type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/timer_list type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/sched_debug type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/firmware type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
```

Comment: try to `mount -o remount,rw /mnt` you can remount the filesystem as read-write by running

Comment: How do you know I need to remount `/mnt`?

Comment: Hi, did the remount work?

Comment: @PiotrMalec - no, I don't know what filesystem to target